# is $((x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_2)) \in R \subseteq \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2 \space if\space x_1=x_2 \space if \space x_1=x_2 $ Transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this a valid argument?

there are only 2 elements that can be created let say $(x_1,y_2) (x_2,y_2)$ and c can not be created. therefore $P \rightarrow Q$ is false and $((x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_2)) \in R \subseteq \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2   \space if\space x_1=x_2 $ is not transitive

Thanks

Comment: I found this totally incomprehensible: what is $P$? What is $Q$? Why can only two elements be created? What is $c$? ...

Comment: Are you trying to argue that a relation with only one ordered pair cannot be transitive?

Comment: @OldJohn I meant transitive is a logic argument of the form $   P \rightarrow Q $ and it is false.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  yes, exactly

Answer (score 2):

I take it you mean for $P$ to be: $(a, b) R (c, d) $ and $(c, d) R (e, f)$

And $Q$ to mean $(a, b) R (e, f)$.

In this case, we do not satisfy $P$: That is, are no ordered pairs for which $P$ holds. (The elements in the ordered pairs need not be distinct).

Therefore, $P$ is false, and the implication $P\rightarrow Q$ is therefore TRUE.

Hence transitivity holds.

Transitivity fails if and only if there exist elements in a relation satisfying $P$, but not satisfying $Q$.

Comment: Needs a TU -> =1

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are asking the following:

> Let $R\subseteq\Bbb{R^2\times R^2}$ be the relation defined as $(x_1,y_1)\mathrel{R}(x_2,y_2)$ if and only if $x_1=x_2$. Is $R$ transitive?

The answer is yes, it is transitive. To see that suppose that $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ are such that $$(x_1,y_1)\mathrel{R}(x_2,y_2)\text{ and }(x_2,y_2)\mathrel{R}(x_3,y_3),$$
then by the definition of $R$ we have $x_1=x_2$ as well $x_2=x_3$. Therefore $x_1=x_3$, and so we can conclude that $(x_1,y_1)\mathrel{R}(x_3,y_3)$ as wanted.